# Software center stopped working after I uninstalled kpackagekit

Tags: package-management, software-center, kde, dependencies, shutter

I uninstalled `kpackagekit` using Ubuntu software center. When it uninstalled, it also uninstalled some dependencies. I was not aware it would do that. Now, if I try to install any software using Ubuntu software center, I get the error

> "This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Futhermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time."

How can I resolve this? For example, when I try to install [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), I get the error

> "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> ```
> shutter: Depends: libxml-simple-perl but it is not installable  
>          Depends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed"
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User, @Arul! It's okay that you asked this here, but just so you know, we have a site just for Ubuntu issues, too. Check it out at [AskUbuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: @Arul Don't crosspost/repost your question there. If you like to see it moved to Ask Ubuntu, flag your question and request migration.

Comment: Migrating to AskUbuntu at the request of the asker.

Comment: why would you uninstall kpackagekit in the first place?, and by the looks of it if you cant reinstall it, you broke your system, seems like you can't update anything now

Comment: @arul -- what version of Ubuntu are you using?  (e.g., 10.04 or 10.10, 32-bit, 64-bit....)  And I'm assuming you're running the Gnome version (just Ubuntu) as opposed to Kubuntu (KDE) or another?

Comment: @jgbelacqua i am using ubuntu 10.04 gnome 32 bit.. Now i upgraded to ubuntu 10.04.2 using alternate cd/dvd option. it solves my issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ALL the issue is resolved. I upgraded to ubuntu 10.04.2 using alternate cd/dvd option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reinstall `kpackagekit` by opening up a terminal. It should be under "Applications" -> "System Tools" or "Accessories" -> "Terminal".

Now type in the following commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after a new line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kpackagekit
```

This should reinstall `kpackagekit` along with its dependencies.

Comment: @Torgamus next time surely post in askubuntu.com ..
@Bloddphilia the first command working fine.. when i run the second one it says 
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  kpackagekit: Depends: kdebase-workspace-bin but it is not installable
               Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not installable
E: Broken packages"